# Specify the element position in the array declaration in C++

Tags: c++, c

In C it is often very helpful to specify the element position when doing an array declaration.

eg:

```
int appliance_id_from_mode[] = {
    [MASTER] = 0,
    [SLAVE] = 1
};
```

This declaration verbatim does not seem to work in c++ ( or at least g++ ), is there any equivalent?

Comment: Is that actually legal C code? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Yes, that is valid C99 code ("designated initializers"), but unluckily not C++. There is no good workaround either.

Answer (score 4):

this looks like a use for map?

```
std:map<??, int> apl_id_mode;
mode[MASTER] = 0;
mode[SLAVE] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not supported in C++, you can expand that into the equivalent declarations:

```
int appliance_id_from_mode[ (MASTER > SLAVE? MASTER : SLAVE) + 1 ] = {};
appliance_id_from_mode[ MASTER ] = 0;
appliance_id_from_mode[ SLAVE ] = 1;
```

Not quite pretty... but should work. If MASTER and SLAVE are values of an enum, you can create a third NUMBER_OF_MODES entry that will avoid the need for the cumbersome size calculation in the array size...

Comment: Thanks, this would help for a two element array, what I actually intended to have is a many element array, but my example was misleading. Will have a look at the map solution.

Comment: This is independent of the number of elements in the array, and the indices that you want to write, while there is more code, it could theoretically be used in a macro, and the difference with the map is that you get direct lookup with a smaller memory footprint. In general I would advice to use a map or unordered map for lookups, but if you have code that is already working as the question suggests, then this is the direct translation to C++ (or C89)

Answer (score 0):

```
enum { MASTER = 0, SLAVE = 1 };
```

Comment: MASTER and SLAVE are constants or #defines, so this would unfortunately not work.

Answer (score -1):

Don't think that such language equivalent exists (at least) in standard C++. However for readability you can surely do a favor using `/*comments*/`!

```
int appliance_id_from_mode[] = {
    /* MASTER */ 0,
    /* SLAVE */ 1
};
```

Comment: don't think `MASTER` and `SLAVE` are meant to be comments

Comment: @Nim, OP hasn't mentioned their meaning, just declared an `int[]`. At the most, I think `MASTER/SLAVE` are something like `enum` value to point an index. Not sure.

Comment: MASTER and SLAVE are not comments, rather the intended index that the element should be stored in the array.

Comment: @user496487, that's what I mentioned in my comment earlier. But such index is not possible to put in an array. So, you have to satisfy with putting them as comment

Answer (score -1):

[C# has such kind of luxury](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). By default we (C++ programmers) doesn't have that luxury under C++. IMO, just accept it and take the pain rather than providing confusing code by using other means instead of plain arrays.